# parquet file codec conversion

Tags: hive, parquet, trino

I have a parquet file which has compression codec BROTLI. BROTLI is not supported by [trino](https://github.com/trinodb/trino/blob/master/lib/trino-parquet/src/main/java/io/trino/parquet/ParquetCompressionUtils.java#L65)
Therefore, I need to convert it to a supported codec which is GZIP, SNAPPY,.. Conversion doesn't seem straight forward or at least i could not find any python library which does it. Please share your ideas or strategies for this codec conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with `pyarrow`. It can brotli-compressed Parquet files.

```py
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

table = pq.read_table(<filename>)
pq.write_table(table, <filename)
```

This will save it as a snappy-compressed file by default. You can specify different compression schemes using the `compression` keyword argument.